# unity SceneManager.sceneLoaded callBack overlay each other when sceneLoaded is finished every time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, callback

```
SceneManager.sceneLoaded += jumpCallBack;
```

I put this in `Start()` and use

```
private void jumpCallBack(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode sceneType)
{
    Debug.Log("ok");
}
```

as callback print, also I have a button, click and load this scene again.

The first time sceneLoaded finished , it print "ok" once, and I click button to load scene again, but this time, it print "ok" twice. Also click button and load again it print 3 times.   Why ? How to make this call back just run once each time the sceneLoaded is called?

Comment: Which object's Start() method are you reffering to?

Comment: Btw, your problem is that you subscribe each time that scene is loaded with the 0
SceneManager.sceneLoaded += jumpCallBack; line. You could try moving this line into the Awake() method, which only runs once in a scene.

Comment: @Zserbinator that's not really true .. `Awake` and `Start` are both called only once - just in different places/times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you want to avoid multiple callbacks

- First of all I would usually unsubscribe before subscribing. This is valid even though if the callback was never added yet but makes sure it is definitely there only once - for **this object**

  ```
   SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= jumpCallBack;
   SceneManager.sceneLoaded += jumpCallBack;
  ```
- And then I think so far you were only lucky that you are only using a static method `Debug.Log` but nothing else in your callback. I suspect you forgot to unsubscribe when your object is destroyed

  ```
  private void OnDestroy()
  {
      SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= jumpCallBack;
  }
  ```

Beyond that it is hard to say without having more details about your project. If you are using e.g. `DontDestroyOnLoad` then you will want to also make sure there is only one instance of this object (Singleton Pattern).

Comment: It is not working in unity 2020.3.33.f1 :( sceneLoaded never call

Comment: @lacas it is hard to tell what happens in your specific use case .. Note that this answer to this question was focused on "How to avoid multiple callbacks for the event" .. if the event is invoked at all depends on your project ;) Do you ever call `SceneManager.LoadScene` anywhere?

Comment: @derHugo I'm newbee to Unity. Do I need to create an empty GameObject in the scene, and attach the script above to that empty GameObject to handle events related to scene?

Comment: @hbprotoss it is the easiest way .. you can however as well use a `static` class and [`[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute-ctor.html) and attach a callback to the event there .. depends on your needs